# Boolean modifier is giving intersection instead of difference

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I cannot get the boolean modifier right in the following file: [para3.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz6tf7z613j6l41/para3.blend)

What I want is to subtract the parabolic shape ("para") from the cube.

The cube is supposed to have some kind of trough after the operation.

Comment: -1 for uploading to Dropbox and deleting the .blend... now that the file is gone is unavailable for future users...

Comment: I suggest you to check what suggested by both answers, it could be one thing, the other or both. First, check the scale: it should not be negative, otherwise normal visualization will show orientation opposite to reality. When/if scale is positive, check/fix normals.

Answer (score 3):

You need to unify the normal vectors of your parabola extrusion and then the boolean will display correctly.

[image]

To unify the normal vectors:

1. Select the parabola extrusion in the 3D view
2. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode
3. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all of the mesh
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals of the outsides
   This makes all of the faces point in the same direction which is necessary for Boolean operations (and a lot of other stuff) to work correctly.
5. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to exit edit mode.  You'll need to hide the 'Para' object to see the effect as shown.

Comment: It's shift+n to recalculate normals

Answer (score 0):

Clearing normals doesn't help in most of my cases

The issue I was seeing was **negative scale** components: if you select an object and its scale in Transform tab and it has negative components (just had 1,-1,1) - change it to positive.

INSTANT FIX for me at least ;)

Comment: If making positive scale components reverts your mirror operations - you'd apply scale (Ctrl-A) instead & then make normals consistent

Comment: Negative scale was indeed my problem, but applying the scale is a better and faster fix.